# Porting RIP ON SDN as an application

Tags: sdn

I have been insisted to "Port RIP On SDN" as my final year project.
But my doubt is like when the controller has an intelligence of routing , whys RIP on SDN. Is there any other advantage of using RIP as an application in SDN ? Is this a valid project to proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

I think in SDN you can use [link-state routing protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-state_routing_protocol) because in SDN you have information of all nodes in network, but you can use such distributed algorithm between SDN controllers. Frameworks like hyperflow (for more information see HyperFlow: A Distributed Control Pane for OpenFlow paper) use this idea for distributed control pane.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the path finding logic of RIP or any other routing protocol on the topology discovered through SDN southbound protocols to find a path for routing traffic. Then you need to insert the rules which reflect this path on the dataplane.